# Can the Internet Achive capture anything malicious?

Tags: xss

I have been using the site Internet Achive when I was researching a domain name and found an older version of the domain I was investigating turned out to be a NSFW web site it seemed like it was going to show a pop up because my browser blocked and warned me about it.

This had me wondering can the Internet Archive pick up anything malicious while it was archiving a site say for example:

A site was attacked by an XSS someone archived the site while the attack was active assuming the Internet Archive captured the code can viewing that archive trigger the attack or what about an archived site that had a drive by attack enabled?

Answer (score 2):

The Internet Archive stores whatever was on that site at the time it crawled it so yes, there could be malicious code there. I understand they make some checks, but you should always assume that it is as malicious as a current site, although likely with older malware :-)